# A drowning man will catch a straw. (vs. catch at a straw)

Tags: verbs, idiomatic-language

> A drowning man will catch a straw. (also correct?)

> A drowning man will catch at a straw. (a commonly used and fixed expression: maxim)

'catch a straw' is also idiomatic? You know the verb 'catch' is both transitive and intransitive.

question is: catch a straw is also acceptable?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct".  You have spelled "drowning" wrong, and the proverb is usually "will clutch at a straw".  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_drowning_man_will_clutch_at_a_straw (It's not very common)  Do you understand the metaphorical meaning of the proverb?  Do you want to know if your version is a variant of the proverb, or grammatically correct.

Comment: I learned that "A drowning man will catch at a straw." and wonder if 'catch a straw' can replace 'catch at a straw'.

Comment: You have the proverb wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite what other people have told you *catch at a straw* is the older form of the proverb, and is still heard, though *clutch at a straw* is more common now. See [here](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/clutch-at-a-straw.html).

*Catch at* is not normally used today, but has an implication of trying to reach but not succeeding. If you said *catch a straw*, that implies that the person has successfully caught the straw. Logically, this is just as uselss as failing to, since a straw will be no help to a drowning man; but to my ear *catch a straw* lacks the sense of desperation I hear in *catch at a straw*.

Answer (score 4):

You have the proverb wrong.  It should be "A drowning man will clutch at a straw." It means that a desperate person will try anything, even if it is unlikely to help."

There's no grammar error in "... catch a straw" but that's not the proverb.

If you "clutch at a straw" you reach and try to grab it but unsuccessfully.  If you "catch a straw" you succeed in grasping a straw that has been thrown.  So the meaning is different.

It's not a particularly common proverb in its full form, though expressions like "he's clutching at straws" are common enough.

Comment: In my experience, for US English the more common idiom would probably be "grasping at straws", though obviously "clutching" would be understood as well.